# Group by IFNULL in elasticsearch

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch

I am new in elasticsearch. I have to convert following MYSQL query into elasticsearch query:

```
select * from product group by IFNULL(variant, id);
```

Sample data for product table:

```
id variant name
1    v1    aaa
2    v1    bbb  
3    NULL  ccc
4    NULL  ddd
5    v2    eee
```

Result I need:

```
id variant name
1    v1    aaa 
3    NULL  ccc
4    NULL  ddd
5    v2    eee
```

Comment: you want to group by on `variant` and `id` field if both are `NULL` right ?

Comment: No, group by on variant but if variant is null then on id. Added example output.